# Can you help me identify one serif and one sans font?

Tags: font-identification

[image: GardenVilla Logo]

Hello everyone! Quick & dirty question.
I'm a junior designer - not used to knowing fonts off by heart yet. I need to figure out the names of the two fonts used here, or their closest counterparts. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD! We have a collection of font identification resources, and it is a good idea to try that first. Edit your question and let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increases. http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info

Comment: @Matt Hey, tried Whatfontis and WhatTheFont but it's being a pain because the kerning is so tight on the serif font. Somewhat more successful results for the sans-serif, but still nothing close to the actual font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both fonts are part of the Rotis family.

[Rotis Serif](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/rotis-serif/):

[image: Rotis Serif screenshot]

Retirement Residence is [Rotis Sans Serif](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/rotis-sans-serif/):

[image: Rotis Sans Serif screenshot]

Comment: You should leave some work to topic starter :)

Comment: @Ilan Eh, it was an easy one. If you'd like, you can edit my half of the answer into yours and I can delete mine since our posts are pretty similar. Unless you're ideologically opposed to fully answering the question of course :P

Comment: @Ilan Thanks so much, guys. I don't usually ask but I was stumped on this one, I've never heard of it before! I appreciate the quick response. :)

Comment: @pixelpinch take a look at the 'e' in 'Garden' and the 'C' in "RESIDENCE". Once you know what those look like you'll pick out Rotis every time. It's one of the weirdest fonts I know that has a degree of popularity.

Comment: @Brendan I don't care about your accept. I wanted that the topic starter find the Rotis Sans himself - it was straightforward...

Answer (score 0):

The Garden Villa could be [Rotis Serif Pro 65 font](http://www.myfonts.com/search/rotis+serif+pro+65/fonts/):

[image]

The second you will find yourself my friend.